# proving a value is less than or equal to another value

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

how would i prove that

$\frac{1}{n!}\le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

for $n \ge 1$

i checked

$P(1)$

and it is true.
and now I'm on

$P(n+1)$

and plugged it in

$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\le \frac{1}{2^{n+1-1}}$

i got

$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\le \frac{1}{2^{n}}$

and ended at

$(n+1)! \ge 2^n$

and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You are assuming that $P(n+1)$ is true. From, here you can show $P(n+2)$ is true from the fact that $$(n+1)! =(n+1)\times n! \ge 2\times n! \ge 2^{n}$$ from the inductive hypothesis.

Thus if $P(n)$ is true $\rightarrow$  $P(n+1)$ is true.